Errores al instalar versiones específicas de mediapipe y numpy
Al poner pip install mediapipe==0.10.7 me aparece:

ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement
mediapipie==0.10.7 (from versions: none)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for mediapipie==0.10.7

y lo mismo para pip install numpy==1.23.5
Tengo la version de Python 3.12 para 64 bits
Intenté en un entorno virtual y tampoco me deja descargarlo con: pip inst virtualenv
Cabe recalcar que si pude instalar versiones especificas de: protobuf==3.20.1 y opencv-python==4.8.1.78

A la fecha (abril 2024) MediaPipe no funciona con Python 3.12. Crea un entorno virtual basado en Python 3.10 o 3.11 y se va a instalar correctamente.

Y para crear un entorno virtual, si no estás usando un manejador tipo Anaconda, puedes usar venv que viene incluído en Python. Puedes tener múltiples versiones de Python instaladas en tu computadora, solo que 1 es la que puede estar en PATH y las otras las accedes desde la ruta completa de instalación.
